# Custom redirect after custom form - ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a point model. I use two different forms for some purpose (classic edit/new on site and a smaller one form a Chrome extension).

The question : how to make the custom form redirect to a "Thank you page" instead of redirect to the new point ?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the controller action handling that form?